# Show that the given set is convex and determine when it is a cone

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Consider the set $G$ of all functions $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ of $n$ variables such that $f(\overline{x})=c$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a fixed point and $c \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a given number.

I need to do the following two things:

1. Show that the set $G$ is convex.
2. For which value of $c$ is $G$ a cone? (**Definition**: A set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a **cone** if whenever $x\in C$, then $ax\in C,\,\forall a>0$.)

Here are my attempts. Really, my question is whether they are correct, and if not, what I need to do in order to fix them:

1. Let $f$, $g \in G$. Then, $f(\overline{x})=c$, $g(\overline{x})=c$, and, for $t\in (0,1)$, the convex combination of $f$ and $g$ is $$ h=tf+(1-t)g. $$

So, $$h(\overline{x})=\left[ tf + (1-t)g\right](\overline{x}) \\ = tf(\overline{x})+ (1-t)g(\overline{x}) \\ = tc +(1-t)c \\ = tc + c -tc \\ = c. $$

Therefore, $G$ is convex.

2. Suppose $k\in G$. Then, $k(\overline{x})=c$.

Let $a>0$. What we want is for $ak(\overline{x})=c$ as well, and in order for this to be so, we must have $\displaystyle\frac{c}{a}=c$, $\forall a > 0$

$\displaystyle \frac{c}{a}-c=0\, \implies \, c\left( \frac{1}{a}-1\right)=0.$

But, we want this to hold for ALL $a>0$, not just when $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a}-1=0$. So, we must have that $c=0$.

Now, I am pretty sure that this is the only case where $G$ can be a cone, but I'm not $100$ percent sure...am I missing anything here?

Thanks ahead of time for your time and patience.

Comment: This looks good.  What part were you concerned about?

Comment: Minor edits are needed in the first sentence of the question, I think you mean $\overline{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a fixed point [not $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$], and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a given number [not $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$].

Comment: It does look good. If you want to pursuade yourself further that $c = 0$ is the only possible value, you can further solve your last line to get $c = 0$ or $\frac{1}{a} - 1 = 0$. If $c \neq 0$, then $\frac{1}{a} =  1 \iff a = 1$. So, if you chose $c \neq 0$, then $2k$ fails to be in $G$, so $G$ is not a cone.

Comment: ...or just use $a=2$.

Comment: @TheoBendit that's a good idea! I will. Thanks to both you and Michael.

Comment: @TheoBendit do you know anything about Polar cones? I am having a tremendous amount of trouble figuring out this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449707/finding-the-polar-cone-of-the-given-cone